# MySQL - How to filter rows by a hidden rows sub_id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I have two Tables.
in the First are Articles in the Second Members.
I want a query which shows only records with the members_id of a given ID (`$_GET['id']`) but not the entry with the given ID `($_GET['id'])`

the articles table looks like:

```
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| id | members_id | ArticleName           |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |       1001 | Shirt Nologo          |
|  2 |       1001 | Nike Sneakers         |
|  3 |       1001 | Nike Sneakers for Men |
|  4 |       1031 | Adidas Shirt          |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
```

the members Table looks like:

```
+------+---------+
| id   | nick    |
+------+---------+
| 1001 | Member1 |
| 1031 | Member2 |
+------+---------+
```

I want something like:

```
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| id | members_id | ArticleName           |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
|  2 |       1001 | Nike Sneakers         |
|  3 |       1001 | Nike Sneakers for Men |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
```

with a query like this:

```
//$_GET['id'] == 1
SELECT t1.*,t2.nick 
FROM articles t1 
    LEFT JOIN members t2 ON t1.members_id=t2.id 
WHERE t1.id != '1' 
AND t1.members_id = t1.found_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all ids for a member that has the `id` value you specify -- but not that particular value.  If so:

```
select a.*
from articles a 
where exists (select 1
              from articles a2
              where a2.member_id = a.member_id and a2.id = :id
             ) and
      id <> :id
```

Comment: @Asario "doesn't work" doesn't provide any useful information.  You need to explain what is going wrong.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':id ) and id <> :id' at line 5 |  that's what he tellls me.